# Intersection or Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

I am given a statement:

"70% of Americans think that Donald Trump will be the greatest president"

"30% of Non-Americans think that Donald Trump will be the greatest president"

So how do I put it into mathematical statement:

P(People having opinion Trump will be greatest|People are Americans) = 0.7

Or

P(People having opinion Trump will be greatest AND People are Americans) = 0.7

Can you also suggest how to deal with these confusion in probability?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the first: *given* that you know someone is American, the probability that he will (erroneously IMHO) think Trump the greatest is $0.7$.

The other probability will also depend on how many americans vs non-americans there are.

A numerical example to illustrate : suppose there are 100 Americans, and 900 non-Americans.
Of the first group 70 will think Trump to be great, of the 900, we get 270.
So the probability that people are American *and* think Trump to be great is $\frac{70}{1000} = 0.07$, so quite a bit smaller. In this case the probability that someone is American under the condition that he thinks Trump is great, is $\frac{70}{270+70}$